# creating a site from a template that carries one library with metadata column, said metadata does not work

Tags: 2010, taxonomy, managed-metadata-service

Saving one simple site as a template to re-use it, the only one metadata column that takes one term set does not work. It lets you select the element from the drop down but it does not 'save' it in the properties. Deleting that one column and re-creating it manually, works.

I need that column to work in every site that will be created from the template.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Site Column of type Managed Metadata and using it your library before saving the site as a template?

Comment: you mean instead of having the metadata column as a simple column inside the library?

Comment: Yes, instead of having the metadata column as a simple column inside the library, use the site column instead

Comment: yes, it worked for me, do you think this problem occurs also in SP 2013 and 2016 and online? I am on 2010.

Comment: Cool!. Yes, this is the way to go with SP Online, 2013 and 2016 etc... I will post this as an answer.

Comment: so also SP online has got the same 'problem'?

Comment: I think so, but I will test your scenario on O365 later this week and let you know.

Comment: I have just tested your scenario in O365 - only my recommended method works which is what I expected.

Comment: Have a look at this page (option 2) to get an idea of why the Site Column method works

Comment: https://veenstra.me.uk/2014/04/02/sharepoint-2013-the-splistitem-being-updated-was-not-retrieved-with-all-taxonomy-fields/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your Metadata column that you have created in your library and create a Site Column of type Managed Metadata and use it in your library before saving the site as a template.

Answer (score 0):

We face that problem everytime we restore a backup in a different environment (i.e. deploying from QA to PROD) we need to manually check the Service Application in the Central Administration and link the Managed Metadata Service again in the Content Type configuration, for the field.

You have to take a little care about deleting and re-creating columns so the new one has the same internal field name, if that's important to your project.

Comment: do you think restoring a backup is the same as saving a subsite as a template and re-create a site from said template (in the same site collection)?

Comment: For sharepoint, it seems like the service connection with the list it's disconncted by some reason... Be carefull too if you try to use a template in another environment that has a different sharepoint version (with other CU or SP)...